# Two servers, one domaine

Tags: webserver, hosting, ovh

I have a domain name example.com, and two public IP address now I want to point my domain to server A(192.168.x.x), but if server A crushed or stop working then the domain should automatically goes to server B(192.168.y.y), same application is installed on both server. how can I configure it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)
You need something in front of the servers, that checks which server is responsable